# Substitution and injection from bootstrap.properties doesn' t work

Tags: java, open-liberty, microprofile

In my pom I define some profile-dependent properties

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- localhost -->
            <id>LOCAL</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <ADServiceUID>uid-c0a84980-33489f60-15ca1a4bd66--7ff7</ADServiceUID>
                <LDAPServiceUID>uid-c0a84980-4e8eaad4-15d55058ca2--7efe</LDAPServiceUID> 
                <WLAN_VPNServiceUID>uid-c0a84980-4e8eaad4-15d55058ca2--7ef6</WLAN_VPNServiceUID>
                <MailboxServiceUID>uid-c0a84980-33489f60-15ca1a4bd66--7f1b</MailboxServiceUID>
                <BiolAuthServiceUID>uid-7f001-5698ac8b-15e9a06bf32--7fbf</BiolAuthServiceUID>
                <HestAuthServiceUID>uid-c0a84980--166b2589-1646afda4f8--7ff0</HestAuthServiceUID>
                <ItetAuthServiceUID>uid-7f001-5698ac8b-15e9a06bf32--7fbd</ItetAuthServiceUID>
                <LdapsProxyServiceUID>uid-c0a84980--562f2389-15f29329a10--7126</LdapsProxyServiceUID>
                <OpenDirServiceUID>uid-c0a8f781--4baed631-15ec752b318--7d1a</OpenDirServiceUID>
                <PhysicMailServiceUID>uid-c0a84980-33489f60-15ca1a4bd66--7fed</PhysicMailServiceUID>
                <ADUserPrivGrpServiceUID>uid-ac10be8b-172512a1-15f483b1c37--7fc9</ADUserPrivGrpServiceUID>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Then in my bootstrap.properties I define the same props which should be set depending on the profile I specify when building my application

```
## UIDs of the IT-Services (set in pom)
it-service.ad = ${ADServiceUID}
it-service.ldap = ${LDAPServiceUID}
it-service.wlan_vpn = ${WLAN_VPNServiceUID}
it-service.mailbox = ${MailboxServiceUID}
it-service.biolauth = ${BiolAuthServiceUID}
it-service.hestauth = ${HestAuthServiceUID}
it-service.itetauth = ${ItetAuthServiceUID}
it-service.ldaps_proxy = ${LdapsProxyServiceUID}
it-service.opendirectory = ${OpenDirServiceUID}
it-service.physik_mail = ${PhysicMailServiceUID}
it-service.ad_userprivategroup = ${ADUserPrivGrpServiceUID}
```

I run `mvn clean install` and the bootstrap.properties under target/classes has the values set

```
## UIDs of the IT-Services (set in pom)
it-service.ad = uid-c0a84980-33489f60-15ca1a4bd66--7ff7
it-service.ldap = uid-c0a84980-4e8eaad4-15d55058ca2--7efe
it-service.wlan_vpn = uid-c0a84980-4e8eaad4-15d55058ca2--7ef6
it-service.mailbox = uid-c0a84980-33489f60-15ca1a4bd66--7f1b
it-service.biolauth = uid-7f001-5698ac8b-15e9a06bf32--7fbf
it-service.hestauth = uid-c0a84980--166b2589-1646afda4f8--7ff0
it-service.itetauth = uid-7f001-5698ac8b-15e9a06bf32--7fbd
it-service.ldaps_proxy = uid-c0a84980--562f2389-15f29329a10--7126
it-service.opendirectory = uid-c0a8f781--4baed631-15ec752b318--7d1a
it-service.physik_mail = uid-c0a84980-33489f60-15ca1a4bd66--7fed
it-service.ad_userprivategroup = uid-ac10be8b-172512a1-15f483b1c37--7fc9
```

while the the same file under src/main/liberty/config still has the placeholders.

Moreover, when I try to read these properties in my application, they are **null**

```
@Inject
  @ConfigProperty( name = "it-service.ad" )
  private Provider<String> itServiceADUID;

  @Inject
  @ConfigProperty( name = "it-service.ldap" )
  private Provider<String> itServiceLdapUID;

  @Inject
  @ConfigProperty( name = "it-service.wlan_vpn" )
  private Provider<String> itServiceWlanVpnUID;

  @Inject
  @ConfigProperty( name = "it-service.mailbox" )
  private Provider<String> itServiceMailboxUID;
...

private void initITServiceUIDs()
  {
    this.itServiceUIDs = new HashMap<>();
    this.itServiceUIDs.put("AD", this.itServiceADUID.get());  <--- line 230
    this.itServiceUIDs.put("Ldap", this.itServiceLdapUID.get());
    this.itServiceUIDs.put("Mailbox", this.itServiceMailboxUID.get());
    this.itServiceUIDs.put("Wlan_Vpn", this.itServiceWlanVpnUID.get());
...
  }
```

The error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
[INFO]  at ch.ethz.id.sws.iamws.dirxwsclient.service.ServiceClient.initITServiceUIDs(ServiceClient.java:230)
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: What feature set do you have enabled?

Comment: @Scott Kurz: The feautures in the server.xml are: mpHealth-2.2, mpOpenAPI-1.1, mpConfig-1.4, mpRestClient-1.4, servlet-4.0, jaxrs-2.1, jsonp-1.1, jsonb-1.0, cdi-2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Francesco, first check that the class you are injecting config into is properly enabled as a CDI bean (with a bean definiting annotation or with a valid beans.xml present).

Second, where are you calling `initITServiceUIDs` from? If you call it from a constructor then the fields will not yet have been injected.

Comment: The class is with RequestScoped annotated.You were right. I called it from the constructor. Now I annotated the method with PostConstruct and the values are no more **null**. But the problem, that the values are not substituted with the ones defined in the pom still persist. The HashMap contains ${ADServiceUID}, ${LDAPServiceUID},...

Comment: It's not clear how you are propagating the property values from Maven/POM to the boostrap.properties.    One convenient Maven-centric way, especially useful with profiles, is to use POM properties like `liberty.bootstrap.xyz`.    See [here](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/ci.maven/blob/master/docs/common-server-parameters.md) for more details.

Comment: E.g. you could define a POM property: `<properties><liberty.bootstrap.ADServiceUID>propValue</liberty.bootstrap.ADServiceUID></properties>` which would cause a property:  `ADServiceUID=propValue` to get generated into the  **boostrap.properties** file.